# Compare 2 tables and update one table based on a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

table1

```
name    phoneno    email    status

name1 11111111 email1 

name2 22222222 email2

name3 33333333 email3 

name4 44444444 email4
```

table2

```
deviceaddr

email1

email3
```

Now i need to compare these 2 tables and update my first table such that if `table1.email=table2.deviceaddr` then my table1 should be updated like shown below:

table1

```
name    phoneno    email    status

name1 11111111 email1 present

name2 22222222 email2

name3 33333333 email3 present

name4 44444444 email4
```

How to write the SQL query for this?
I am using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: So, you want to update `status` in table1 where `email` exists in table2 as `deviceaddr`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
update table1
set status = 'present'
where email in (select deviceaddr from table2)
```

Comment: Remember when we had JOINs? Those were the days.